# Design of utilities for diffrent versions of 3rd party library

Tags: .net, versioning, libraries, software-design, code-reuse

I've inherited a project where such solution is applied:

There are 5 versions of 3rd party library. And there 5 projects in the solution with utilities for corresponding version of 3rd party library.

Quite a lot of utility classes in the solution have identical code for all versions of 3rd party library. The duplication problem is solved in such way - the code files that need to be the same for all projects are stored in some common folder and added as a link to all projects.

I do not feel that using links to share code is the best approach.
Could you tell me if it is a bad approach and if it is so, please tell me what is the right way to .resolve such code duplication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly subjective as to whether this is 'bad'.

Linked code files are possible for a reason - sometimes it is necessary to share files like this between multiple projects.

Depending on how different the third party library is between versions - it might be possible to write some wrapper code which deals with these differences and isolates this away.

Comment: I thought about writing wrapper, but it is not applicable in my case for two reasons - 1. the API is quite big (hundreds classes) and writing wrapper is not trivial; 2. writing wrapper classes would move duplication problem to the wrapper.

Comment: You could probably automate most of it with a template or two, generate interfaces, then simply fire up the wrapper implementation required based on the library version. But, yes, still a decent amount of work to do so.